# Opacity gets ignored, using Caliburn.Micro.BindableAppBar Lib

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I found this really cool Library called Caliburn.Micro.BindableAppBar. What is does is to allow me to bind items on an Applicationbar. Just like you would bind a button using MVVM.

XAML code looks like this:

```
<bab:BindableAppBar x:Name="AppBar" Opacity="0.7" Mode="Minimized">
        <bab:BindableAppBarButton x:Name="AddItem"
                                  Text="{Binding AddItemText}"
                                  IconUri="{Binding Icon}" 
                                  Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                  />

        <bab:BindableAppBarMenuItem x:Name="RemoveItem"
                                  Text="Remove"
                                  />
    </bab:BindableAppBar>
```

My problem is that the Opacity i set just gets ignored, like if i just deleted that part of the code. I got no errors nor do i have any warnings in my project. So anyone know why the Opacity won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just going from the [source,](https://github.com/kamranayub/CaliburnBindableAppBar/blob/master/Caliburn.Micro.BindableAppBar/CustomAppBar.cs) it looks like you're setting the wrong property.

Specifically, look at line 310:

```
    public double BarOpacity {
        get { return ApplicationBar.Opacity; }
        set { ApplicationBar.Opacity = value; }
    }
```

Try using `BarOpacity` instead and post your results.